# How to apply BVH data to Rigify

Tags: rigify, bvh

I want to try out the rigify rig on my model, and would like to apply a BVH file to my rig. How can I do this? When I import the BVH, a separate model with the animation shows up, but the rigify rig is unaffected. Is it even possible to copy a different rigs motion data, or am I going to have to copy it manually.

Thx, Daniel

PS: The BVH code is included in the link below, just copy it to a empty notepad file and rename it to: example.bvh .

[https://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~pingelm/ComputerAnimation/Motions/bvh/dance01.bvh](https://pages.cs.wisc.edu/%7Epingelm/ComputerAnimation/Motions/bvh/dance01.bvh)

Comment: The keyword is retargeting. Maybe @josh sanfelici can help you. He did this: https://youtu.be/LU0u_b88K8k (Sorry, I'm not sure how you can contact him here.)

Comment: There are multiple way to solve this. but you must follow the this for better understanding.
http://nerdclub-uk.blogspot.com/2016/11/importing-bvh-files-into-blender-rigify.html

Answer (score 0):

You can apply it through a process called retargeting. I would recommend the Rokoko addon for start.
Here is a video on how to use to retarget to different rigs including Rigify
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Nyxeb48mUfs